# How to insert a record if a relation in another table is missing (sql server)?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I hope you can help me.

I have this scenario:

```
    UserFolders                              Folders                
Id |    UserId  |FolderName |FolderId       Id |FolderName
1  |      1     |  folder1  |   1            1 |  folder1
2  |      2     |  folder1  |   1            2 |  folder2
3  |      2     |  folder2  |   2            3 |  folder3
```

Now, I need that every User has a folder, so if some folders are missing in the table UserFolders I have to insert them. This should be the result:

```
    UserFolders                                             
Id  |UserId    |FolderName  |FolderId       
1   |  1       |   folder1  |   1                 
2   |  1       |   folder2  |   2
3   |  1       |   folder3  |   3
4   |  2       |   folder1  |   1
5   |  2       |   folder2  |   2                 
6   |  2       |   folder3  |   3
```

I've tried LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN but I can't resolve it. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `cross join` and then filter out the ones that exist.  To get the missing pairs:

```
select userid, folderid
from (select distinct userid from userfolders) u cross join
     folders f left join
     userfolders uf
     on uf.userid = u.userid and uf.folderid = f.folderid
where uf.userid is null;
```

Add an `insert` to insert the values into `userfolders`.

Note that I did not include the folder name.  You should not be replicating this data.  Look it up in the `folders` table.

Also, you may have a better source of users, but it is not mentioned in the question.